# How to get the multi level json value in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, json, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a json code:

```
"ACCOUNT":  
    {
        "AmountDue": "$36,812.99",
        "OutstandingBalance": "$27,142.27",
        "StatementTotal": "$9,670.72",
        "StatementDate": "12/6/2018",
        "DueByDate": "12/23/2018",
        "AccountNumber": "5-029-5685-55"
    },
```

I need to get the AmountDue to verify with the portal value. how to fetch this value.

I have tried using Direct ways,

```
String amountToValidate = jsonObj.ParseJson(billMeterJson, "AmountDue").toString();
```

But need to fetch from the multilevel code. any ideas.
I have tried this but getting error.

```
String amountToValidate = jsonObj.ParseJson(billMeterJson, "data.ACCOUNT[0].AmountDue").toString();
```

Comment: What is the output ?

Comment: i need to compare the value in json with the website portal value. for now it is working when in gave it outside the Account. but i need to use it as multilevel json parser as mentioned above

Comment: you can create POJO if your "account" is always the same

Comment: Amount Due, Outstanding Balance etc.. will change dynamically in JSON.

Comment: you could also be lazy, convert to string, and use a regex :P

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly are you trying to do? Write out the entire scenario. This sounds like it has nothing to do with Selenium and more to do with you have a value in JSON that you don't know how to extract.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonPath` from `RestAssured`. It's great library to parse JSON Objects and Arrays.

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In order to parse JSON, you can provide it as a `String` or `File`. Use `JsonPath.from()` and pass it as an argument.

Example JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "ACCOUNT": [
      {
        "AmountDue": "$36,812.99",
        "OutstandingBalance": "$27,142.27",
        "StatementTotal": "$9,670.72",
        "StatementDate": "12/6/2018",
        "DueByDate": "12/23/2018",
        "AccountNumber": "5-029-5685-55"
      },
      {
        "AmountDue": "$40,000.00",
        "OutstandingBalance": "$27,142.27",
        "StatementTotal": "$9,670.72",
        "StatementDate": "12/6/2018",
        "DueByDate": "12/23/2018",
        "AccountNumber": "5-029-5685-55"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Let's jump into the code:

```
        JsonPath path = JsonPath.from("{\r\n" + 
                "  \"data\": {\r\n" + 
                "    \"ACCOUNT\": [\r\n" + 
                "      {\r\n" + 
                "        \"AmountDue\": \"$36,812.99\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"OutstandingBalance\": \"$27,142.27\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"StatementTotal\": \"$9,670.72\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"StatementDate\": \"12/6/2018\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"DueByDate\": \"12/23/2018\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"AccountNumber\": \"5-029-5685-55\"\r\n" + 
                "      },\r\n" + 
                "      {\r\n" + 
                "        \"AmountDue\": \"$40,000.00\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"OutstandingBalance\": \"$27,142.27\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"StatementTotal\": \"$9,670.72\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"StatementDate\": \"12/6/2018\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"DueByDate\": \"12/23/2018\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"AccountNumber\": \"5-029-5685-55\"\r\n" + 
                "      }\r\n" + 
                "    ]\r\n" + 
                "  }\r\n" + 
                "}");
        System.out.println(path.getString("data.ACCOUNT[1].AmountDue"));
```

We are creating the `JsonPath` from String (it doesn't need to be formatted). Then, we use `path.getString()` method to get the desired value. If you need `AmountDue` from the first account, you can just change the index.

The line `System.out.println(path.getString("data.ACCOUNT[1].AmountDue"));` prints `$40,000.00`

If I change it to `System.out.println(path.getString("data.ACCOUNT[0].AmountDue"));` then it prints `$36,812.99`